# Problem with gtsummary tbl_stack and tbl_svysummary for continuous weight variables

Tags: r, gtsummary

**Problem:**

I'm trying to create tabulate tables of a continuous variable of a weight census. I want to separate the mean of this continuous variable by a categorical variable `c("Pobre Extremo", "Pobre No Extremo")`. So my desired table looks something like this (numbers are random):

[image]

This a table from a past year, so when i run my syntax for a new year i run into this problem table:

[image]

I had verified if its a problem of the labelled data but it seems to be fine that side.

**Syntax so far for the tables:**

```
data %>% 
  as_label() %>%
  as_survey_design(weight = fac500a) %>%
  tbl_strata2(
    strata = pobreza,
    ~ .x %>%
      tbl_svysummary(
        by = ocupinf,
        include = ing_cap,
        missing = "no",
        statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean}"),
        label = list(ing_cap = .y)
      ) %>%
      modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**") %>%
      add_overall(., col_label = "Total"),
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack",
    .combine_args = list(group_header = NULL)
  ) %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x %>%
      mutate(variable = "pobreza", row_type = "level") %>%
      tibble::add_row(
        row_type = "label",
        variable = "pobreza",
        label = "pobreza",
        .before = 1L
      )
  ) %>%
  modify_column_indent(columns = label, rows = row_type == "level") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "ing_cap: Mean")
```

**This is my data:**

I run function `dput()`:

```
structure(list(ing_cap = structure(c(3153.9033203125, 3153.9033203125, 
3153.9033203125, 3153.9033203125, 2420.76844618056, 1920.38439941406, 
1920.38439941406, 2773.28385416667, 3264.26846590909, 3264.26846590909, 
4211.30403645833, 3283.44856770833, 3481.44609375, 3481.44609375, 
6730.44587053571, 6730.44587053571, 6730.44587053571, 3571.64485677083, 
3571.64485677083, 6990.048828125, 6990.048828125, 6990.048828125, 
6374, 6374, 6374, 3532.215625, 5201.203125, 5201.203125, 4516.51395089286, 
4516.51395089286, 10841.1783854167, 10841.1783854167, 10841.1783854167, 
6081.54609375, 6081.54609375, 6081.54609375, 6081.54609375, 3669.76139322917, 
3669.76139322917, 3669.76139322917, 3460.72778320312, 5076.026953125, 
2791.3478515625, 5264.654296875, 5264.654296875, 3697.99633789062, 
3697.99633789062, 5197.804296875, 4063.18391927083, 3975.13313802083, 
3975.13313802083, 6428.6640625, 6428.6640625, 5685.87834821429, 
5685.87834821429, 5685.87834821429, 5685.87834821429, 5737.10049715909, 
5737.10049715909, 4644, 4644, 4644, 5124.6, 5124.6, 1830.73010253906, 
3699.47631835938, 8673.4296875, 8673.4296875, 8673.4296875, 3629.81884765625, 
3629.81884765625, 6726.15364583333, 6726.15364583333, 6726.15364583333, 
5125.9521484375, 5125.9521484375, 7991.56591796875, 7991.56591796875, 
8089.87926136364, 8089.87926136364, 8089.87926136364, 8089.87926136364, 
2730.0802734375, 13985.8271484375, 13985.8271484375, 13985.8271484375, 
13985.8271484375, 5944.7998046875, 5944.7998046875, 5944.7998046875, 
2476.12651909722, 2476.12651909722, 2476.12651909722, 2476.12651909722, 
13624, 7012.70654296875, 7012.70654296875, 7012.70654296875, 
7012.70654296875, 6648.0015625), label = "Ingreso per cápita en el hogar", class = c("haven_labelled_spss", 
"haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), fac500a = structure(c(354.4443359375, 
269.111877441406, 467.653961181641, 467.653961181641, 345.380615234375, 
1201.30834960938, 1262.73962402344, 1383.26965332031, 1191.63061523438, 
935.718688964844, 769.666625976562, 1235.62524414062, 391.513061523438, 
341.510711669922, 391.513061523438, 287.484558105469, 287.484558105469, 
334.339538574219, 291.639129638672, 262.072875976562, 251.327713012695, 
251.327713012695, 347.6591796875, 229.84504699707, 255.283050537109, 
221.039138793945, 258.418426513672, 329.677368164062, 217.956893920898, 
242.079177856445, 420.243377685547, 536.125610351562, 467.653961181641, 
258.418426513672, 247.823104858398, 242.079177856445, 247.823104858398, 
536.125610351562, 403.013153076172, 393.672302246094, 334.339538574219, 
345.244873046875, 506.461639404297, 376.046264648438, 417.665008544922, 
178.606018066406, 218.673873901367, 334.339538574219, 167.823974609375, 
267.186492919922, 316.787017822266, 446.065185546875, 294.903411865234, 
287.572387695312, 329.677368164062, 247.823104858398, 258.418426513672, 
404.189147949219, 404.189147949219, 267.218231201172, 404.189147949219, 
352.567840576172, 216.117523193359, 323.650573730469, 287.572387695312, 
329.677368164062, 329.677368164062, 287.572387695312, 217.956893920898, 
329.677368164062, 287.572387695312, 287.572387695312, 329.677368164062, 
242.079177856445, 334.339538574219, 291.639129638672, 262.072875976562, 
245.502563476562, 221.039138793945, 291.639129638672, 245.502563476562, 
245.502563476562, 334.339538574219, 205.848175048828, 234.055160522461, 
228.630340576172, 311.361968994141, 205.848175048828, 234.055160522461, 
271.596160888672, 221.039138793945, 245.502563476562, 251.327713012695, 
251.327713012695, 258.418426513672, 217.956893920898, 258.418426513672, 
242.079177856445, 329.677368164062, 355.819549560547), label = "Factor de Expansión de Empleo/Ingresos proyecciones CPV-2007", format.spss = "F8.2"), 
    ocupinf = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2), label = "Situación de informalidad (ocup.principal)", format.spss = "F8.2", labels = c(`empleo informal` = 1, 
    `empleo formal` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), pobreza = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), label = "pobreza", format.spss = "F8.2", labels = c(`Pobre Extremo` = 1, 
    `Pobre No Extremo` = 2, `No Pobre` = 3), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Let me know if you spot any insights.

Comment: Do you just need to add `tbl_svysummary(type = everything() ~ "continuous")`?

Comment: that solve the deal, thanks very much @DanielD.Sjoberg

Comment: I invite you to see how i'm using gtsummary for my [thesis](https://santiagosotelo.netlify.app/posts/tablas_tesis/). Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DanielD.Sjoberg specified in the comments, it was necessary to explicit that every variable in the rows was a continuous variable. So add `type = everything() ~ "continuous"` to the code:

```
data %>% 
  as_label() %>%
  as_survey_design(weight = fac500a) %>%
  tbl_strata2(
    strata = pobreza,
    ~ .x %>%
      tbl_svysummary(
        by = ocupinf,
        include = ing_cap,
        missing = "no",
        type = everything() ~ "continuous",
        statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean}"),
        label = list(ing_cap = .y)
      ) %>%
      modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**") %>%
      add_overall(., col_label = "Total"),
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack",
    .combine_args = list(group_header = NULL)
  ) %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x %>%
      mutate(variable = "pobreza", row_type = "level") %>%
      tibble::add_row(
        row_type = "label",
        variable = "pobreza",
        label = "pobreza",
        .before = 1L
      )
  ) %>%
  modify_column_indent(columns = label, rows = row_type == "level") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "ing_cap: Mean")
```